# Dialog box is not pop up when timer expires in QML Programming?

Tags: qt, qml

i want to create a task logger in QML need to call every one hour as notification pop to fill up what we have done for every one hour and record it in text file .

I tried writing a code in QML . so that i get a pop up every hour so that i can log the task i have done in one hour and it get submitted as text file with time stamp.

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 300
    title: "Task Tracker"


//Timer implemented to test the code to show dialog after every 6 seconds



    Timer {
        id: minuteTimer
        interval: 1000 * 6 // 6 seconds in milliseconds
        onTriggered: {
            showTaskEntryDialog()
        }
        running: true
        repeat: true
    }


//function to show Task Entry Dialog

    function showTaskEntryDialog() {
        console.log("showTaskEntryDialog called")
        var dialog = taskInputDialog.createObject()
        dialog.accepted.connect(function() {

//if dialog text is not empty then save to file

            if (dialog.taskInput.text !== "") {
                saveTaskToFile(dialog.taskInput.text)
            }
            dialog.destroy()
        })
        dialog.rejected.connect(function() {
            dialog.destroy()
        })
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        // You can add more UI elements here if needed

     Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Task Tracker - Minute notifications"
            font.pixelSize: 18
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: taskInputDialog
   
     // on component on complete we try to display dialog 


        Dialog {
            id: dialog
            x: 100
            y: 100
            width: 300
            height: 100
            title: qsTr("Enter Completed Task")
            standardButtons: Dialog.Ok | Dialog.Cancel

            TextField {
                id: taskInput
                width: parent.width - 20
                placeholderText: "Enter the completed task"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is another code which i try to use Dialog box .This also not working . After exhausted with below method i went to call rectangle to update the state .

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 300
    title: "Test Dialog Component"

    Button {
        text: "Show Dialog"
        onClicked: {
            var dialog = taskInputDialog.createObject()
            dialog.accepted.connect(function() {
                if (dialog.taskInput.text !== "") {
                    console.log("Entered task:", dialog.taskInput.text);
                }
                dialog.destroy();
            })
            dialog.rejected.connect(function() {
                dialog.destroy();
            })
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: taskInputDialog

   // created  dialog 

        Dialog {
            id: dialog
            width: 300
            title: "Enter Task"
            standardButtons: Dialog.Ok | Dialog.Cancel

            TextField {
                id: taskInput
                width: parent.width - 20
                placeholderText: "Enter a task"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code  is not working

Comment: You're not specifying a parent in the `createObject()` function. Does it work if you give it a parent?

Comment: Why are you doing this with a Component and a Loader? It would be sufficient to place the dialog itself in the ApplicationWIndow, saving you the trouble of createObject (which indeed needs a parent to become visible), just calling open()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this with a `Loader`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: mainWindow
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    //Timer implemented to test the code to show dialog after every 6 seconds
    Timer {
        id: minuteTimer
        interval: 1000 * 6 // 6 seconds in milliseconds
        onTriggered: {
            showTaskEntryDialog()
        }
        running: true
        repeat: true
    }

    //function to show Task Entry Dialog
    function showTaskEntryDialog() {
        console.log("showTaskEntryDialog called")
        loader.active = true;
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        // You can add more UI elements here if needed

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Task Tracker - Minute notifications"
            font.pixelSize: 18
        }
    }

    // loader handles visibility of dialog
    Loader {
        id: loader
        sourceComponent: taskInputDialog
    }

    Component {
        id: taskInputDialog

        // on component on complete we try to display dialog

        Dialog {
            id: dialog
            x: 100
            y: 100
            width: 300
            height: 100

            // bind visibility to loader
            visible: loader.active

            title: qsTr("Enter Completed Task")
            standardButtons: Dialog.Ok | Dialog.Cancel

            function saveTaskToFile(text) {
                console.log("save " + text);
            }

            onAccepted: {
                if (taskInput.text !== "") {
                    saveTaskToFile(taskInput.text)
                }
                loader.active = false
            }
            onRejected: loader.active = false

            TextField {
                id: taskInput
                width: parent.width - 20
                placeholderText: "Enter the completed task"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: resolved with the same